# Django rename method previously used in migration

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I have a model.py file that looks something like

```
def method_to_rename(instance, filename):
  return 'somthing/' + filename

class Person(models.Model):
  photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=method_to_rename)
```

This model has been through a couple of migrations. Now I'd like to rename the `method_to_rename` to `method_renamed`

When I run `makemigrations` I get the following error triggered by the method existing in previous migrations:

> AttributeError: module 'person.models' has no attribute
>   'method_to_rename'

Am I able to rename this method? I understand that the upload_to method has had some issues previously.

Answer (score 1):

The method is probably also referenced inside the migration files you create with "makemigrations". Changing the reference there should fix your problem.

But make sure this does not break the state of your current database.